# How do I remount a partition to read and write permanently in the terminal

Tags: boot-partition, mountpoint

Everytime I boot the system and log in via `tty` I have to run the following command in order to mount the partition as `rw`

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda6/
```

It seems like the partition is always mounted in `read only mode`.

How do I fix this?

*SOURCE* :`/dev/sda6`

*FSTYPE* :`ext4`

*OPTIONS* :`ro,relatime,data=ordered`

Comment: Depend on what file system is on the partition. What entry do you have for sda6 in /etc/fstab ? Is the hard drive failing ? Generally, you would add an entry on fstab as command line fixes are not going to survive a reboot (a you can see).

Comment: The options your provided is `ro` which means read only. Is it from the `fstab` entry ? If yes, i think that is the issue.